# socket.io port for every chat room javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and I see that it is asking for port number to listen and connect etc. But one thing I don't understand. I want to make a small social media for my office. Everyone can chat in private and as well as in group. So, I'm confused. Should I use different ports for every chat session? if yes then is there any range of ports which I can use? or is there any other way to initiate private chat and group chat. How to use port for every chat session?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use a separate port for each chat room.  All users connect to the same server on the same port.  You can then set up chat rooms on that one socket.io server for any given set of users that you want to have join that room (all using the same port).  Each set of users that you wish to be in the same chat session can be put in the same chat room by the server and they will then be able to communicate with one another via the chat room.  This chat room capability is built into socket.io.

In fact, socket.io is even built to share the same port as your web page (typically port 80) and this simplifies access control as you won't run into same origin restrictions or have to implement CORS in the server.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you please tell me where can I find an example or tutorial on how to separate chat rooms or something similar. Again thank you so much for your help and explanation.

Comment: @SharikShaikh - I don't quite know what you are looking for.  The [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) shows how you can join a socket.io connection to an arbitrary chat room name and then you can send messages to anyone in that chat room.  It's up to you how you design an interface to connect two people into their own chat room.  socket.io supports the underlying infrastructure for two or more people to share messages in a chat room.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)